# A generalization of Pythagoras'

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, plane-geometry

Consider a quadrilateral inscribed in a semicircle of diameter $d$, as in the picture below, then $$d^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \frac{2 a b c}{d}$$
[image: inscribed_in_half_circle]

Notes:

1. If one of the $a$, $b$, $c$ equals $0$, we get [Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)'
2. An older [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991194/cyclic-hexagon-circumradius) on this site asks (essentially) to determine $d$ if $(a,b,c) = (2,7,11)$.
3. The set $\{ (a,b,c,d) \ | d^3 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)d + 2 a b c\}$ [can](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%5E3%20-%20%28a%5E2%20%2B%20b%5E2%20%2B%20c%5E2%29d%20-%202%20a%20b%20c%2F.%20%7Ba-%3Ep%28-p%5E2%20%2B%20q%5E2%20%2B%20r%5E2%29%2C%20b-%3Eq%28p%5E2%20-%20q%5E2%20%2B%20r%5E2%29%2C%20c-%3E%20r%28p%5E2%20%2B%20q%5E2%20-%20r%5E2%29%2C%20d-%3E2%20p%20q%20r%7D) be parametrized by
   \begin{eqnarray}
   a &=& p(-p^2 + q^2 + r^2)\\
    b&=&q(p^2 - q^2 + r^2)\\
    c&=& r(p^2 + q^2 - r^2)\\
   d&=& 2 p q r
   \end{eqnarray}
4. Provided as [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Any feedback would be appreciated!

$\bf{Added:}$

1. will write an answer tomorrow, perhaps some users would like to solve it on their own.
2. In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991194/cyclic-hexagon-circumradius/2040485#2040485) of  @Cristhian Camacho to the older problem linked, we find  this formula.

$\bf{Added:}$

A possible solution : the relation is equivalent to

$$1 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2 x y z$$
where $x = \frac{a}{d}, \ldots$, but then also $x = \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}, \ldots$, with $\alpha+ \beta + \gamma = \pi$. Now we have to show that if $u + v+w =  \frac{\pi}{2}$, then

$$ 1- (\sin^2 u + \sin^2 v + \sin^2 w) - 2 \sin u \sin v \sin w$$
In fact we have a [factoring](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-%20%28%20Sin%5Bu%5D%5E2%20%2B%20Sin%5Bv%5D%5E2%20%2B%20Sin%5Bw%5D%5E2%29%20-%202%20Sin%5Bu%5D%20Sin%5Bv%5D%20Sin%5Bw%5D%2F%2FTrigFactor).

Equivalently, one can show that if $\phi+ \psi + \theta = \pi$ ( angles of a triangle) then

$$1 = \cos^2 \phi + \cos^2 \psi + \cos^2 \theta + 2 \cos \phi \cos \psi \cos \theta$$

( $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{2}, \ldots$). This also provides the parametrization of the set, using [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) for the $\cos$ in a triangle.

$\bf{Added:}$ Just an idea how to handle more general things: say we want to determine a relation between the cosines of some angles with a  sum a given rational multiple of $\pi$. Write $x_i = \cos \phi_i$, with $\sum \phi_i = \frac{ k \pi}{l}$. Then $\cos \phi_i = \frac{1}{2}( t_i + \frac{1}{t_i})$ and $(t_1 \cdots t_n)^l = (-1)^k$. Eliminating $t_i$ from the above gets a relation between the $x_i$. It could be rather involved, but  [our case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bs%5E2-2x%20s%2B1%2Ct%5E2-2y%20t%2B1%2Cu%5E2-2z%20u%2B1%2Cs%20t%20u%2B1%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%2C%7Bs%2Ct%2Cu%7D%5D) is simple( $\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 = \pi$, so $t_1 t_2 t_3 + 1 = 0$, and we get $1 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + 2 x_1 x_2 x_3$).

Comment: Do you have a proof? if so include it to "show work" in hope to avoid question close votes.

Comment: @coffeemath:  will write one soon, just in case somebody wants  to solve it, it's not difficult :-)

Comment: Sorry, just noticed "provided as challenge" [still a proof maybe along with asking for other proofs would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the figure,

$$x=y$$
$$\because  \sin y = \frac{c}{d}$$
$$\therefore \sin x = \frac{c}{d} $$

Using Cosine Rule on $\Delta ABC$,

\begin{align}
AC^2 &= a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(90^{\text {o}}+x) \\
&= a^2+b^2+2ab\sin x \\
&= a^2+b^2+2ab\left(\frac{c}{d} \right) \\
&= a^2+b^2+\frac{2abc}{d}
\end{align}

In $\Delta ACD$,
$$AD^2 = CD^2+AC^2$$
$$d^2=c^2+a^2+b^2+\frac{2abc}{d}$$

Comment: Nice and clean!  +1

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Clearly, due to $90^\circ$ subtended by the diameter on the semicircle, the diagonals are $\sqrt{d^2-a^2}$ and $\sqrt{d^2-c^2}$. By Ptolemy theorem, which says that product of diagonals of a cyclic quadrilateral equals the sum of products of opposite sides, we have
$$\sqrt{d^2-a^2}\cdot\sqrt{d^2-c^2}=ac+bd$$
On squaring and simplifying, this rearranges into
$$d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{2abc}{d}$$

Comment: Great solution.  Remarkably efficient!

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the figure below, I've added lines joining the $2$ points on the upper part of the circle to the center (labeled $O$), and labeled the points around the circle, starting from the left and going clockwise, as $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$.

[image: Diagram of OP with lines added and points labeled]

With $r$ being the circle's radius, we have

$$\lvert AO\rvert = \lvert BO\rvert = \lvert CO\rvert = \lvert DO\rvert = r \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, label the angles in the the upper semi-circle around the point $O$ as

$$\measuredangle AOB = \alpha, \; \measuredangle BOC = \beta, \; \measuredangle COD = \gamma, \;\;\; \alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, using the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) on $\triangle AOB$, $\triangle BOC$ and $\triangle COD$ gives

$$a^2 = r^2 + r^2 - 2r^2\cos\alpha = 2r^2(1 - \cos\alpha) = \frac{d^2}{2}(1 - \cos\alpha) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$b^2 = r^2 + r^2 - 2r^2\cos\beta = 2r^2(1 - \cos\beta) = \frac{d^2}{2}(1 - \cos\beta) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$c^2 = r^2 + r^2 - 2r^2\cos\gamma = 2r^2(1 - \cos\gamma) = \frac{d^2}{2}(1 - \cos\gamma) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Adding the above $3$ equations together results in

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = \frac{d^2}{2}(3 - (\cos\alpha + \cos\beta + \cos\gamma)) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

As shown in [Prove trigonometry identity for $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176892), we have

$$\cos\alpha + \cos\beta + \cos\gamma = 1 + 4\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

By drawing perpendicular bisector lines from $O$ to each of $AB$, $BC$ and $CD$, we see that

$$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \frac{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{r} = \frac{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)} = \frac{a}{d} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Similarly, $\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right) = \frac{b}{d}$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right) = \frac{c}{d}$. Substituting these into \eqref{eq7A}, and then that result into \eqref{eq6A}, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 & = \frac{d^2}{2}\left(3 - 1 - \frac{4abc}{d^3}\right) \\
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 & = d^2 - \frac{2abc}{d} \\
d^2 & = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \frac{2abc}{d}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Comment: Nice!  ($2$ is in the numerator, look at half of a regular hexagon)

Comment: @orangeskid You're right, I forgot the factor of $4$ in the equation for the sum of cosines. Thanks for letting me know. I've now corrected my answer accordingly.